# Java default Certificates missing, even if they are in the correct location

Tags: java, gradle, certificate, runtime-error, java-17

Any time I run any program that tries to run pure Java code (Coding programs, ENVs and some compiled programs based on it. It does not effect apps that are using Java tho)

For example when I try to run Gradle it gives me an error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Same for other programs

I have uninstalled all jdk and jre files and reinstalled them and changed the JAVA_HOME and Path variable but still it gives me that error. I don't connect to any SSL or other custom servers just the default java ones, so I don't understand why the default certificates in the cacerts file do not work.
I think, but I'm not sure, it happened when Java updated. Since then, like 2 months ago, it was like this

Btw I did try to use keytool but it requires a .cer file witch I don't have in Java 17 (to my knowledge)

Edit: Here is the trace

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:529)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:308)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.getConnection(DownloadUtils.java:243)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.DownloadUtils.downloadManifest(DownloadUtils.java:307)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.json.Util.getVanillaVersion(Util.java:73)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.actions.ServerInstall.run(ServerInstall.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.InstallerPanel.run(InstallerPanel.java:423)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.launchGui(SimpleInstaller.java:175)
    at net.minecraftforge.installer.SimpleInstaller.main(SimpleInstaller.java:147)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
    ... 29 more
Failed to download version manifest, can not find server jar URL.
```

Comment: Check the target host certificate if it expire or not.

Comment: What... I'm just trying to play modded Minecraft and making some mods. Can you elaborate?

Comment: So the java program try to connect to a host and the there is a certificate issue from the error log. It means you don’t have a valid certificate to make SSL/TLS connection. To fix it, you should add that certificate to your jvm with the keytool. Or actually that certificate of the host expire

Comment: But I don't have any certificates and I'm not using any online conections. I'm having problems with Java default certificates. Because everything that I can't do on this machine I can do it on a different one

Comment: Would that be you have multiple jdk in that machine?

Comment: I had jdk 17 and jre 8, but after that started happening I tried to download an older version (jdk 17 was an newer version of jdk that the program required). I downloaded jdk 16 and changed the variables, it did the same thing. I did have more jdk files a long time ago but I managed between then without a problem

Comment: I just read that you were talking for that different machine. No it only had jre 8 and jdk 17 on it

Comment: Ok. Maybe a detailed error trace would help?

Comment: Here it is in the post

Comment: I think the issue is the jre8 and it may contain expired SSL certificate. Could you try to replace it entirely with a newer version and try again?

Comment: I did it before, now again. Still not working